# In Minecraft, how much is a redstone repeater tick?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

In Minecraft, there are these redstone repeaters that look like this.
[image]

How much is one tick? Is 2 2x longer, how much?

Comment: Did you searched for it before asking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Repeater):

> When initially placed, a redstone repeater has a delay of 1 redstone tick (equivalent to 2 game ticks, or 0.1 seconds).
>
> By right-clicking on the repeater once, a repeater's delay can be set from 1 to 2 ticks (indicated by the distance between the two small redstone torches on the top of the repeater) right-clicking again makes a three-tick delay, right-clicking again makes a four-tick delay, and right clicking again resets back to one. Longer delays can be made with multiple repeaters – for example, a repeater set to '4' and another to '1' will give a half second delay (0.4s + 0.1s = 0.5s).
>
> A repeater set to a delay of 2-4 ticks will increase the length of any shorter pulse to match the length of the repeater's delay. For example, a repeater set to a 4-tick delay will change any shorter pulse into a 4-tick pulse.